# Install CentOS Web Panel (CWP) on CentOS 8

Tags: installation, centos, compatibility, centos-web-panel, centos8

This is a fresh install of CentOS 8 on a dedicated server with dual Xenon (20 cores) and 24GB of RAM. There are no other things installed, so CWP is the first thing to go on there. There are a couple of bugs with the install that we need to resolve to get CWP to install on CentOS 8.

```
# sh cwp-el7-latest
CentOS Web Panel repo for Linux 7 - x86_64       10 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00
MariaDB                                         2.6 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:01
Package epel-release-8-7.el8.noarch is already installed.
Package wget-1.19.5-7.el8_0.1.x86_64 is already installed.
Package screen-4.6.2-10.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
dnf makecache: error: argument timer: invalid choice: 'fast' (choose from 'timer')
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
No match for argument: MariaDB
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb
No match for argument: MariaDB-server
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb-server
Error: Unable to find a match
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
No match for argument: cpulimit
No match for argument: links
Error: Unable to find a match
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
... (already installed items)
No match for argument: perl-Crypt-SSLeay
Error: Unable to find a match
No match for argument: exim
No match for argument: sendmail
Dependencies resolved.
...

Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:27 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
No match for argument: dovecot-pigeonhole
Error: Unable to find a match
cwp-el7-latest: line 158: mysql: command not found
cwp-el7-latest: line 159: mysql: command not found

PREPARING THE SERVER
##########################
setenforce: SELinux is disabled

#############################################
Please wait... installing web server files...
#############################################

Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:48 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                        Arch     Version              Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 cwp-httpd                      x86_64   2.4.39-3             cwp         5.5 M
 apr-util                       x86_64   1.6.0-1              cwp         103 k
 apr                            x86_64   1.6.2-1              cwp         228 k
Installing dependencies:
 compat-openssl10               x86_64   1:1.0.2o-3.el8       AppStream   1.1 M
 dwz                            x86_64   0.12-9.el8           AppStream   109 k
 efi-srpm-macros                noarch   3-2.el8              AppStream    22 k
 ghc-srpm-macros                noarch   1.4.2-7.el8          AppStream   9.3 k
 go-srpm-macros                 noarch   2-16.el8             AppStream    14 k
 libpq                          x86_64   10.5-1.el8           AppStream   188 k
 ocaml-srpm-macros              noarch   5-4.el8              AppStream   9.4 k
 openblas-srpm-macros           noarch   2-2.el8              AppStream   7.9 k
 perl                           x86_64   4:5.26.3-416.el8     AppStream    72 k
 perl-Algorithm-Diff            noarch   1.1903-9.el8         AppStream    52 k
 perl-Archive-Tar               noarch   2.30-1.el8           AppStream    79 k
 perl-Archive-Zip               noarch   1.60-3.el8           AppStream   108 k
 perl-Attribute-Handlers        noarch   0.99-416.el8         AppStream    88 k
 perl-B-Debug                   noarch   1.26-2.el8           AppStream    26 k
 perl-CPAN                      noarch   2.18-397.el8         AppStream   554 k
 perl-CPAN-Meta                 noarch   2.150010-396.el8     AppStream   191 k
 perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements    noarch   2.140-396.el8        AppStream    37 k
 perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML            noarch   0.018-397.el8        AppStream    34 k
 perl-Compress-Bzip2            x86_64   2.26-6.el8           AppStream    72 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2        x86_64   2.081-1.el8          AppStream    40 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib         x86_64   2.081-1.el8          AppStream    68 k
 perl-Config-Perl-V             noarch   0.30-1.el8           AppStream    22 k
 perl-DB_File                   x86_64   1.842-1.el8          AppStream    83 k
 perl-Data-OptList              noarch   0.110-6.el8          AppStream    31 k
 perl-Data-Section              noarch   0.200007-3.el8       AppStream    30 k
 perl-Devel-PPPort              x86_64   3.36-5.el8           AppStream   118 k
 perl-Devel-Peek                x86_64   1.26-416.el8         AppStream    93 k
 perl-Devel-SelfStubber         noarch   1.06-416.el8         AppStream    75 k
 perl-Devel-Size                x86_64   0.81-2.el8           AppStream    34 k
 perl-Digest                    noarch   1.17-395.el8         AppStream    27 k
 perl-Digest-MD5                x86_64   2.55-396.el8         AppStream    37 k
 perl-Digest-SHA                x86_64   1:6.02-1.el8         AppStream    66 k
 perl-Encode-devel              x86_64   4:2.97-3.el8         AppStream    39 k
 perl-Env                       noarch   1.04-395.el8         AppStream    21 k
 perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder         noarch   1:0.280230-2.el8     AppStream    48 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Command          noarch   1:7.34-1.el8         AppStream    19 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Embed            noarch   1.34-416.el8         AppStream    79 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Install          noarch   2.14-4.el8           AppStream    46 k
 perl-ExtUtils-MM-Utils         noarch   1:7.34-1.el8         AppStream    17 k
 perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker        noarch   1:7.34-1.el8         AppStream   300 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Manifest         noarch   1.70-395.el8         AppStream    37 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Miniperl         noarch   1.06-416.el8         AppStream    76 k
 perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS          noarch   1:3.35-2.el8         AppStream    83 k
 perl-File-Fetch                noarch   0.56-2.el8           AppStream    33 k
 perl-File-HomeDir              noarch   1.002-4.el8          AppStream    61 k
 perl-File-Which                noarch   1.22-2.el8           AppStream    23 k
 perl-Filter                    x86_64   2:1.58-2.el8         AppStream    82 k
 perl-Filter-Simple             noarch   0.94-2.el8           AppStream    29 k
 perl-IO-Compress               noarch   2.081-1.el8          AppStream   258 k
 perl-IO-Socket-IP              noarch   0.39-5.el8           AppStream    47 k
 perl-IO-Zlib                   noarch   1:1.10-416.el8       AppStream    80 k
 perl-IPC-Cmd                   noarch   2:1.02-1.el8         AppStream    43 k
 perl-IPC-SysV                  x86_64   2.07-397.el8         AppStream    43 k
 perl-IPC-System-Simple         noarch   1.25-17.el8          AppStream    43 k
 perl-JSON-PP                   noarch   1:2.97.001-3.el8     AppStream    68 k
 perl-Locale-Codes              noarch   3.57-1.el8           AppStream   311 k
 perl-Locale-Maketext           noarch   1.28-396.el8         AppStream    99 k
 perl-Locale-Maketext-Simple    noarch   1:0.21-416.el8       AppStream    78 k
 perl-MRO-Compat                noarch   0.13-4.el8           AppStream    24 k
 perl-Math-BigInt-FastCalc      x86_64   0.500.600-6.el8      AppStream    27 k
 perl-Math-BigRat               noarch   0.2614-1.el8         AppStream    40 k
 perl-Memoize                   noarch   1.03-416.el8         AppStream   118 k
 perl-Module-Build              noarch   2:0.42.24-5.el8      AppStream   273 k
 perl-Module-CoreList           noarch   1:5.20181130-1.el8   AppStream    87 k
 perl-Module-CoreList-tools     noarch   1:5.20181130-1.el8   AppStream    22 k
 perl-Module-Load               noarch   1:0.32-395.el8       AppStream    19 k
 perl-Module-Load-Conditional   noarch   0.68-395.el8         AppStream    24 k
 perl-Module-Loaded             noarch   1:0.08-416.el8       AppStream    74 k
 perl-Module-Metadata           noarch   1.000033-395.el8     AppStream    44 k
 perl-Net-Ping                  noarch   2.55-416.el8         AppStream   101 k
 perl-Net-SSLeay                x86_64   1.85-6.el8           AppStream   358 k
 perl-Package-Generator         noarch   1.106-11.el8         AppStream    27 k
 perl-Params-Check              noarch   1:0.38-395.el8       AppStream    24 k
 perl-Params-Util               x86_64   1.07-22.el8          AppStream    44 k
 perl-Perl-OSType               noarch   1.010-396.el8        AppStream    29 k
 perl-PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint    noarch   0.08-395.el8         AppStream    13 k
 perl-Pod-Checker               noarch   4:1.73-395.el8       AppStream    33 k
 perl-Pod-Html                  noarch   1.22.02-416.el8      AppStream    87 k
 perl-Pod-Parser                noarch   1.63-396.el8         AppStream   108 k
 perl-SelfLoader                noarch   1.23-416.el8         AppStream    82 k
 perl-Software-License          noarch   0.103013-2.el8       AppStream   138 k
 perl-Sub-Exporter              noarch   0.987-15.el8         AppStream    73 k
 perl-Sub-Install               noarch   0.928-14.el8         AppStream    27 k
 perl-Sys-Syslog                x86_64   0.35-397.el8         AppStream    50 k
 perl-Test                      noarch   1.30-416.el8         AppStream    89 k
 perl-Test-Harness              noarch   1:3.42-1.el8         AppStream   279 k
 perl-Test-Simple               noarch   1:1.302135-1.el8     AppStream   516 k
 perl-Text-Balanced             noarch   2.03-395.el8         AppStream    58 k
 perl-Text-Diff                 noarch   1.45-2.el8           AppStream    45 k
 perl-Text-Glob                 noarch   0.11-4.el8           AppStream    17 k
 perl-Text-Template             noarch   1.51-1.el8           AppStream    64 k
 perl-Thread-Queue              noarch   3.13-1.el8           AppStream    24 k
 perl-Time-HiRes                x86_64   1.9758-1.el8         AppStream    61 k
 perl-Time-Piece                x86_64   1.31-416.el8         AppStream    98 k
 perl-URI                       noarch   1.73-3.el8           AppStream   116 k
 perl-Unicode-Collate           x86_64   1.25-2.el8           AppStream   686 k
 perl-autodie                   noarch   2.29-396.el8         AppStream    98 k
 perl-bignum                    noarch   0.49-2.el8           AppStream    44 k
 perl-devel                     x86_64   4:5.26.3-416.el8     AppStream   599 k
 perl-encoding                  x86_64   4:2.22-3.el8         AppStream    68 k
 perl-experimental              noarch   0.019-2.el8          AppStream    24 k
 perl-inc-latest                noarch   2:0.500-9.el8        AppStream    25 k
 perl-libnet                    noarch   3.11-3.el8           AppStream   121 k
 perl-libnetcfg                 noarch   4:5.26.3-416.el8     AppStream    77 k
 perl-local-lib                 noarch   2.000024-2.el8       AppStream    74 k
 perl-open                      noarch   1.11-416.el8         AppStream    77 k
 perl-perlfaq                   noarch   5.20180605-1.el8     AppStream   386 k
 perl-srpm-macros               noarch   1-25.el8             AppStream    11 k
 perl-utils                     noarch   5.26.3-416.el8       AppStream   128 k
 perl-version                   x86_64   6:0.99.24-1.el8      AppStream    67 k
 python-srpm-macros             noarch   3-37.el8             AppStream    14 k
 python3-rpm-macros             noarch   3-37.el8             AppStream    13 k
 qt5-srpm-macros                noarch   5.11.1-2.el8         AppStream    11 k
 redhat-rpm-config              noarch   116-1.el8.0.1        AppStream    82 k
 rust-srpm-macros               noarch   5-2.el8              AppStream   9.2 k
 systemtap-sdt-devel            x86_64   4.0-7.el8            AppStream    79 k
 make                           x86_64   1:4.2.1-9.el8        BaseOS      498 k
 perl-Carp                      noarch   1.42-396.el8         BaseOS       30 k
 perl-Data-Dumper               x86_64   2.167-399.el8        BaseOS       58 k
 perl-Encode                    x86_64   4:2.97-3.el8         BaseOS      1.5 M
 perl-Errno                     x86_64   1.28-416.el8         BaseOS       76 k
 perl-Exporter                  noarch   5.72-396.el8         BaseOS       34 k
 perl-File-Path                 noarch   2.15-2.el8           BaseOS       38 k
 perl-File-Temp                 noarch   0.230.600-1.el8      BaseOS       63 k
 perl-Getopt-Long               noarch   1:2.50-4.el8         BaseOS       63 k
 perl-HTTP-Tiny                 noarch   0.074-1.el8          BaseOS       58 k
 perl-IO                        x86_64   1.38-416.el8         BaseOS      141 k
 perl-MIME-Base64               x86_64   3.15-396.el8         BaseOS       31 k
 perl-Math-BigInt               noarch   1:1.9998.11-5.el8    BaseOS      195 k
 perl-Math-Complex              noarch   1.59-416.el8         BaseOS      108 k
 perl-PathTools                 x86_64   3.74-1.el8           BaseOS       90 k
 perl-Pod-Escapes               noarch   1:1.07-395.el8       BaseOS       20 k
 perl-Pod-Perldoc               noarch   3.28-396.el8         BaseOS       86 k
 perl-Pod-Simple                noarch   1:3.35-395.el8       BaseOS      213 k
 perl-Pod-Usage                 noarch   4:1.69-395.el8       BaseOS       34 k
 perl-Scalar-List-Utils         x86_64   3:1.49-2.el8         BaseOS       68 k
 perl-Socket                    x86_64   4:2.027-2.el8        BaseOS       59 k
 perl-Storable                  x86_64   1:3.11-3.el8         BaseOS       98 k
 perl-Term-ANSIColor            noarch   4.06-396.el8         BaseOS       46 k
 perl-Term-Cap                  noarch   1.17-395.el8         BaseOS       23 k
 perl-Text-ParseWords           noarch   3.30-395.el8         BaseOS       18 k
 perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap            noarch   2013.0523-395.el8    BaseOS       24 k
 perl-Time-Local                noarch   1:1.280-1.el8        BaseOS       34 k
 perl-Unicode-Normalize         x86_64   1.25-396.el8         BaseOS       82 k
 perl-constant                  noarch   1.33-396.el8         BaseOS       25 k
 perl-interpreter               x86_64   4:5.26.3-416.el8     BaseOS      6.3 M
 perl-libs                      x86_64   4:5.26.3-416.el8     BaseOS      1.6 M
 perl-macros                    x86_64   4:5.26.3-416.el8     BaseOS       72 k
 perl-parent                    noarch   1:0.237-1.el8        BaseOS       20 k
 perl-podlators                 noarch   4.11-1.el8           BaseOS      118 k
 perl-threads                   x86_64   1:2.21-2.el8         BaseOS       61 k
 perl-threads-shared            x86_64   1.58-2.el8           BaseOS       48 k
 python3-pyparsing              noarch   2.1.10-7.el8         BaseOS      142 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 perl-Encode-Locale             noarch   1.05-9.el8           AppStream    21 k
 perl-IO-Socket-SSL             noarch   2.060-2.el8          AppStream   289 k
 perl-Mozilla-CA                noarch   20160104-7.el8       AppStream    15 k
 perl-TermReadKey               x86_64   2.37-7.el8           AppStream    40 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  160 Packages

Total download size: 30 M
Installed size: 95 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/160): apr-util-1.6.0-1.x86_64.rpm            148 kB/s | 103 kB     00:00
  ... (removed for space limitations on stackoverflow)
(160/160): perl-interpreter-5.26.3-416.el8.x86_ 7.6 MB/s | 6.3 MB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           5.6 MB/s |  30 MB     00:05
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1
  Installing       : perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch                    1/160
  ... (removed for space limitations on stackoverflow)
  Installing       : perl-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64                       159/160
  Running scriptlet: cwp-httpd-2.4.39-3.x86_64                          160/160
  Installing       : cwp-httpd-2.4.39-3.x86_64                          160/160
  Running scriptlet: cwp-httpd-2.4.39-3.x86_64                          160/160
  Verifying        : cwp-httpd-2.4.39-3.x86_64                            1/160
  ... (removed for space limitations on stackoverflow)
  Verifying        : python3-pyparsing-2.1.10-7.el8.noarch              160/160

Installed:
  cwp-httpd-2.4.39-3.x86_64
  apr-util-1.6.0-1.x86_64
  apr-1.6.2-1.x86_64
  perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-9.el8.noarch
  perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.060-2.el8.noarch
  perl-Mozilla-CA-20160104-7.el8.noarch
  perl-TermReadKey-2.37-7.el8.x86_64
  compat-openssl10-1:1.0.2o-3.el8.x86_64
  dwz-0.12-9.el8.x86_64
  efi-srpm-macros-3-2.el8.noarch
  ghc-srpm-macros-1.4.2-7.el8.noarch
  go-srpm-macros-2-16.el8.noarch
  libpq-10.5-1.el8.x86_64
  ocaml-srpm-macros-5-4.el8.noarch
  openblas-srpm-macros-2-2.el8.noarch
  perl-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-Algorithm-Diff-1.1903-9.el8.noarch
  perl-Archive-Tar-2.30-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Archive-Zip-1.60-3.el8.noarch
  perl-Attribute-Handlers-0.99-416.el8.noarch
  perl-B-Debug-1.26-2.el8.noarch
  perl-CPAN-2.18-397.el8.noarch
  perl-CPAN-Meta-2.150010-396.el8.noarch
  perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.140-396.el8.noarch
  perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML-0.018-397.el8.noarch
  perl-Compress-Bzip2-2.26-6.el8.x86_64
  perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.081-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.081-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Config-Perl-V-0.30-1.el8.noarch
  perl-DB_File-1.842-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Data-OptList-0.110-6.el8.noarch
  perl-Data-Section-0.200007-3.el8.noarch
  perl-Devel-PPPort-3.36-5.el8.x86_64
  perl-Devel-Peek-1.26-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-Devel-SelfStubber-1.06-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Devel-Size-0.81-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-Digest-1.17-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Digest-MD5-2.55-396.el8.x86_64
  perl-Digest-SHA-1:6.02-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Encode-devel-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64
  perl-Env-1.04-395.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder-1:0.280230-2.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-Command-1:7.34-1.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-Embed-1.34-416.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-Install-2.14-4.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-MM-Utils-1:7.34-1.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-1:7.34-1.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-Manifest-1.70-395.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-Miniperl-1.06-416.el8.noarch
  perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS-1:3.35-2.el8.noarch
  perl-File-Fetch-0.56-2.el8.noarch
  perl-File-HomeDir-1.002-4.el8.noarch
  perl-File-Which-1.22-2.el8.noarch
  perl-Filter-2:1.58-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-Filter-Simple-0.94-2.el8.noarch
  perl-IO-Compress-2.081-1.el8.noarch
  perl-IO-Socket-IP-0.39-5.el8.noarch
  perl-IO-Zlib-1:1.10-416.el8.noarch
  perl-IPC-Cmd-2:1.02-1.el8.noarch
  perl-IPC-SysV-2.07-397.el8.x86_64
  perl-IPC-System-Simple-1.25-17.el8.noarch
  perl-JSON-PP-1:2.97.001-3.el8.noarch
  perl-Locale-Codes-3.57-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Locale-Maketext-1.28-396.el8.noarch
  perl-Locale-Maketext-Simple-1:0.21-416.el8.noarch
  perl-MRO-Compat-0.13-4.el8.noarch
  perl-Math-BigInt-FastCalc-0.500.600-6.el8.x86_64
  perl-Math-BigRat-0.2614-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Memoize-1.03-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-Build-2:0.42.24-5.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-CoreList-1:5.20181130-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-CoreList-tools-1:5.20181130-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-Load-1:0.32-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-Load-Conditional-0.68-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-Loaded-1:0.08-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Module-Metadata-1.000033-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Net-Ping-2.55-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Net-SSLeay-1.85-6.el8.x86_64
  perl-Package-Generator-1.106-11.el8.noarch
  perl-Params-Check-1:0.38-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Params-Util-1.07-22.el8.x86_64
  perl-Perl-OSType-1.010-396.el8.noarch
  perl-PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint-0.08-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Checker-4:1.73-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Html-1.22.02-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Parser-1.63-396.el8.noarch
  perl-SelfLoader-1.23-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Software-License-0.103013-2.el8.noarch
  perl-Sub-Exporter-0.987-15.el8.noarch
  perl-Sub-Install-0.928-14.el8.noarch
  perl-Sys-Syslog-0.35-397.el8.x86_64
  perl-Test-1.30-416.el8.noarch
  perl-Test-Harness-1:3.42-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Test-Simple-1:1.302135-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-Balanced-2.03-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-Diff-1.45-2.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-Glob-0.11-4.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-Template-1.51-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Thread-Queue-3.13-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Time-HiRes-1.9758-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Time-Piece-1.31-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-URI-1.73-3.el8.noarch
  perl-Unicode-Collate-1.25-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-autodie-2.29-396.el8.noarch
  perl-bignum-0.49-2.el8.noarch
  perl-devel-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-encoding-4:2.22-3.el8.x86_64
  perl-experimental-0.019-2.el8.noarch
  perl-inc-latest-2:0.500-9.el8.noarch
  perl-libnet-3.11-3.el8.noarch
  perl-libnetcfg-4:5.26.3-416.el8.noarch
  perl-local-lib-2.000024-2.el8.noarch
  perl-open-1.11-416.el8.noarch
  perl-perlfaq-5.20180605-1.el8.noarch
  perl-srpm-macros-1-25.el8.noarch
  perl-utils-5.26.3-416.el8.noarch
  perl-version-6:0.99.24-1.el8.x86_64
  python-srpm-macros-3-37.el8.noarch
  python3-rpm-macros-3-37.el8.noarch
  qt5-srpm-macros-5.11.1-2.el8.noarch
  redhat-rpm-config-116-1.el8.0.1.noarch
  rust-srpm-macros-5-2.el8.noarch
  systemtap-sdt-devel-4.0-7.el8.x86_64
  make-1:4.2.1-9.el8.x86_64
  perl-Carp-1.42-396.el8.noarch
  perl-Data-Dumper-2.167-399.el8.x86_64
  perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64
  perl-Errno-1.28-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-Exporter-5.72-396.el8.noarch
  perl-File-Path-2.15-2.el8.noarch
  perl-File-Temp-0.230.600-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Getopt-Long-1:2.50-4.el8.noarch
  perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.074-1.el8.noarch
  perl-IO-1.38-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64
  perl-Math-BigInt-1:1.9998.11-5.el8.noarch
  perl-Math-Complex-1.59-416.el8.noarch
  perl-PathTools-3.74-1.el8.x86_64
  perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.07-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.28-396.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.35-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Pod-Usage-4:1.69-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Scalar-List-Utils-3:1.49-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-Socket-4:2.027-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-Storable-1:3.11-3.el8.x86_64
  perl-Term-ANSIColor-4.06-396.el8.noarch
  perl-Term-Cap-1.17-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap-2013.0523-395.el8.noarch
  perl-Time-Local-1:1.280-1.el8.noarch
  perl-Unicode-Normalize-1.25-396.el8.x86_64
  perl-constant-1.33-396.el8.noarch
  perl-interpreter-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-libs-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-macros-4:5.26.3-416.el8.x86_64
  perl-parent-1:0.237-1.el8.noarch
  perl-podlators-4.11-1.el8.noarch
  perl-threads-1:2.21-2.el8.x86_64
  perl-threads-shared-1.58-2.el8.x86_64
  python3-pyparsing-2.1.10-7.el8.noarch

Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:19 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
Package cwp-suphp-0.7.2-3.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

#############################################
Please wait... Installing PHP ...
#############################################

Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:20 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:22:59 PM EST.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides libpng15.so.15()(64bit) needed by cwp-php-5.6.37-1.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) needed by cwp-php-5.6.37-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Compiler requires 512 MB RAM + SWAP
Installation FAILED at php
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   899  100   899    0     0   1872      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1869
sh: line 36: mysql: command not found
sh: line 46: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory
Received
#
```

In order to try to resolve the errors, which seem to be primarily this:

```
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides libpng15.so.15()(64bit) needed by cwp-php-5.6.37-1.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) needed by cwp-php-5.6.37-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Compiler requires 512 MB RAM + SWAP
Installation FAILED at php
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   899  100   899    0     0   1872      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1869
sh: line 36: mysql: command not found
sh: line 46: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory
```

Firstly, I tried to install php manually, and was able to successfully do so with `yum install php`. However, the installer still proceeded with the identical problem, nothing changed.

The preceeding errors like `nothing provides libpng15.so.15()(64bit)` I tried to resolve by manually installing libpng, but it seems that libpng is already installed.

```
# yum install libpng
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:35 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 03:26:25 PM EST.
Package libpng-2:1.6.34-5.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

However, it's possibly because `libpng15` as asked for by cwp is an older package. See https://pkgs.org/download/libpng15.so.15()(64bit), which I found the rpm for CentOS at https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64.rpm.html

An attempt to install libpng15 from the rpm (since it can't be found with `yum install libpng15`), results in another error:

```
c# rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.lWZHpk: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        package libpng-2:1.6.34-5.el8.x86_64 (which is newer than libpng-2:1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64) is already installed
        file /usr/share/man/man5/png.5.gz from install of libpng-2:1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libpng-2:1.6.34-5.el8.x86_64
```

It seems that libpng16 is already installed, so libpng15 can't be installed with libpng16 installed.

The error, `Compiler requires 512 MB RAM + SWAP` doesn't make sense, since I have 24GB of RAM.

Here is my setup:

```
# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                2.0G   18M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root   13G  1.9G   11G  15% /
/dev/mapper/cl-tmp   5.5G   72M  5.4G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/cl-home  199G  1.5G  198G   1% /home
/dev/sda1            2.0G  182M  1.7G  10% /boot
tmpfs                3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

The error `sh: line 36: mysql: command not found` comes from the fact that I can't seem to get mysql installed due to MariaDB conflict.

The error `grep: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory` seems to be because apache is not installed, of course, possibly because the script ended without installing it? Not sure.

Please help me get CentOS Web Panel installed on CentOS 8. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there! any progress about this questions 8 months later?

Comment: @mariomol I gave up on CWP

Answer (score 2):

As of today, a beta version of the CWP for Centos 8 is available. [CWP Documentation for install on Centos 8](https://control-webpanel.com/installation-instructions#step4)

Answer (score 0):

the CWP is not supporting centos 8 yet, they are working on it.
I recommend waiting until they officially support centos 8.

Comment: do u have any reference that says that they are working on it or any progress/expected dates?

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to install cwp with the appropriate shell script, if you try to install cwp for CentOS 7 on a CentOS 8 is natural it's not working.

cwp-el7-latest it's only for CentOS 7, link:
wget https://centos-webpanel.com/cwp-el7-latest

cwp-el8-latest it's only for CentOS 8, link:
wget https://centos-webpanel.com/cwp-el8-latest

Answer (score 0):

As per [CWP Installation Instructions](https://control-webpanel.com/installation-instructions), they have installation for CentOS 8. Below are the instructions:

```
#cd /usr/local/src
#wget http://centos-webpanel.com/cwp-el8-latest
#chmod +x cwp-el8-latest
#bash cwp-el8-latest
```

The shell script shall install all the necessary packages through yum.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install CWP on Centos8

1.Login to server/VPS through SSH by using root login

2.Update the server and install wget, use below commands.

```
yum update -y
yum install wget
```

3.Go to src directory, as below

```
cd /usr/local/src/
```

4.Download the latest version of CWP, using below commands

```
wget http://centos-webpanel.com/cwp-el8-latest
```

5.Start CWP control panel installation.

```
sh cwp-el7-latest
```

It will take around 30-60 mins for its complete installation, also you will get all details after installation. Like CWP login url and details.
Once the installation is completed, you will get the following messages as shown in the following image.